# Is there any difference between python scripts in airflow and same script in python

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, airflow

I was writing the below code but it is running endless in airflow, but in my system it take 5 min to run

```
gc=pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file='file.json')

sh3 = gc.open("city")

wks3 = sh3.worksheet_by_title("test")

df = wks3.get_as_df()
df2 = demo_r
wks3.clear()
wks3.set_dataframe(df2,(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering just the question in the title because we can't do anything about your code without more details (stack trace/full code sample/infra setup/etc).

Airflow is a Python framework and will run any code you give it. So there is no difference between a Python script run via an Airflow task or just on your laptop -- the same lines of code will be executed. However, do note that Airflow runs Python code in a separate process, and possibly on different machines, depending on your chosen executor. Airflow registers metadata in a database and manages logfiles from your tasks, so there's more happening around your task when you execute it in Airflow.